# how to send and receive data wifi hotspot board to for react native app?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-ios

I would like to create an react native app that can connect to a Hotspot WiFi board and be able to receive and send data for example turn on a light, but I have not been able to find the right package for this. 
this board develop by c++
Please help me  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPeI3.jpg)

Answer (score -1):

You should use [`react-native-wifi-p2p`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-wifi-p2p)

this is a library to provide WiFi Direct (Peer-To-Peer, P2P) service to react-native.

**Important:** currently only Android support realized. If you want to provide iOS support, then you should note to [`react-native-multipeer`](https://github.com/lwansbrough/react-native-multipeer) repository.